# Yii2 how to display images saved in web folder

Tags: image, yii2

I have images saved in /web/uploads/PROJECT in Yii2. How do i display them on page? below is my codes but its broken link image.

Controller:

```
$img = Yii::$app->request->baseUrl.'/web/uploads/PROJECT/';
$image = Html::img($img.$img_obj['AVATAR'],["width"=>"600px"]);
```

View:

```
echo $data;
```

Do i have to set any rights to display it? Right-clicking and opening image in new tab shows the url "/web/uploads/PROJECT/3fioobapJ5vRk_wdCEzDJbQWyO66inWO.jpg" which seems to be correct but page displays "Not Found (#404)"

Can anyone kindly advise? Thanks!

Comment: Are you using Apache? Show your `.htaccess`.

Comment: isn't web the public folder in yii? if so shouldn't it be `$img = 'uploads/PROJECT/';`?

Comment: Yes, most likely it's the reason, overlooked it.

Comment: i have changed it but still it shows a broken link. In source codes it shows <img src="uploads/PROJECT/3fioobapJ5vRk_wdCEzDJbQWyO66inWO.jpg" width="600px" alt=""> I am using a shared development server running LAMP but am not sure where is the .htaccess file

Comment: @esiaz, your answer isn't work for me(i use yii2 advanced template). What do you think, what's wrong

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Strangely, using the below codes displays the images correctly.

```
$img = Url::to('@web/uploads/PROJECT/').$img_obj['AVATAR'];                 
$image = '<img src="'.$img.'" width="600" />';  


 <img src="<?= Yii::$app->request->baseUrl . '/backend/web/uploads/' . $model->profile_photo ?>" class=" img-responsive" >  
<?php echo Html::img('@web/img/icon.png', ['class' => 'pull-left img-responsive']); ?>
```

Answer (score 11):

The static images should be placed inside web/any_folder_name

to access in YII 2:

```
<?= Html::img('@web/any_folder_name/bg1.jpg', ['alt'=>'some', 'class'=>'thing']);?>
```

Comment: This works for me. Thanks :) I have tried prepending the `@backend` alias to 'web/images/sample.png' but I always get a broken image. I'm just wondering why `@web` is more correct than `@backend`? :)

Answer (score 2):

Add this code in your Grid View:

```
        [
            'attribute'=>'photo',
            'value' =>  Html::a(Html::img(Yii::getAlias('@web').'/image/'.$st_data->photo, ['alt'=>'some', 'class'=>'thing', 'height'=>'100px', 'width'=>'100px']), ['site/zoom']),
            'format' => ['raw'],
        ],
```

Comment: For path only this helped me: Yii::getAlias('@web').'/image/img.gif' Thanks